# Using a Dell laptop screen as the screen for a different device

Tags: linux, console

So I'm making a home made gaming console, and I want to use my dell laptop as the screen (I don't want to reach behind my desk to get the HDMI cable out of my actual pc to connect it to my normal monitor), it is a very old laptop which runs Linux mint.

I have a cable that runs from HDMI to USB (my laptop does not have an HDMI slot, yes it's that old) with the HDMI part plugged in my console.

Does anybody know a way to set up my laptop so it can be used as a screen? I've tried looking into the BIOS for options but didn't get any further.

Comment: Any solution would mean you couldn't use the laptop screen for the laptop.

Comment: As long as I would be able to reverse it when I'm done this would not be a problem.

Comment: The process would be definitely be destrutive to the laptop and would not be reversable.

Comment: That would be a bit too much sadly, I guess I'll just have to grab the HDMI cable I'm using in my pc in order to work on my console. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the second video plug on the monitor or use a HDMI switch?  You would be able to simply press a button on the switch, to change which device, would be displayed on the monitor.

Comment: That might work, although I don't have a HDMI switch, I might try to get one if I can't find a VGA cable or somehing along those lines.

Comment: It maybe possible, but would be outside of the scope of this site - electrical engineering might be able to help, as might the raspi stack.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR : You can't do that in a simple way.

Long story short, a laptop's screen is made to receive a signal and output it not the contrary. Even if the laptop was equipped with HDMI, that would be an output that is wired to the GPU that would be used for an external monitor connection.

Using the laptop's screen by itself requires a direct connection (with an adapter ?) to the screen, which will disable it's capacity to show the laptop's output signal.

Answer (score 0):

There were several models of iMac that allowed you to use them as external monitors : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592 .  However, that was a very custom solution that Apple created, and I haven't heard of other computer manufacturers doing it.  Sorry.